# Enable/Disable "Like" button using REST API

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, rest

I have a `Likes count` column in a custom list .

I am trying to update the likecount from client side using REST API.

If a user has clicked on `Like` once, then it should disable the like button for that user.

It should only allow user to do that once. Any ideas out there?

Comment: Hey, see here for my blog post about that: https://afrait.com/blog/like-list-items-facebook-like-en/ and here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/163301/formating-list-with-jslink-like-button/163304#163304. Maybe this helps

Comment: thank u but its not soo relevant

Comment: i want to do with REST API

Comment: For me it looks pretty like REST in my blog, but maybe I am wrong?!

Comment: not its not soo different  but you are doing alot ,in my case i have just one title columns which need to be liked soo code should be very simple than yours. just GetCount for selected item and if user clicked before then disable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a count column you could have multi-value user column. The count of likes is the number of values in that column. So if the users ID is in the field, he will not be allowed to press like again.

Example:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: URL + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('FeedLikes')/items?
                       $select=Title,Users/ID&$expand=Users/ID"
```

Returned object:

```
 {"Users":[{"ID":30},{"ID":21}]}
```